# How to dynamically add/remove show fields in Sonata Admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I wanted to remove some show fields that are only relevant if some other fields have a certain value, but the entity cannot be accessed from the admin class.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to override the admin controller's preShow action:

```
// FooAdminController.php

/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Foo     $object
 *
 * @return null|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
protected function preShow(Request $request, $object)
{
    $ret = parent::preShow($request, $object);

    /** @var FieldDescriptionCollection $show */
    $show = $this->admin->getShow();
    if ($object->isBar()) {
        $show->remove('baz');
    }

    return $ret;
}
```